# Nothing happens when I run program

Tags: c

The guys just helped me with a problem, got solved 100%, but now I have another one.

I compile my files and everything without problems, but when i want to run the program nothing happens.

enter.c : http://pastebin.com/GGzVeAhw
simple_interest.c: http://pastebin.com/XdESrxSk

This is how my header file looks like:

```
int enter(void);
double Calc_Interest(double principal, double rate, int term);
double Calc_Amount(double principal, double interest);
double Calc_Payments(double total, int term);
void Display_Results(double principal, double interest, double total, double mPay);
```

PS This forum is really helpful, especially for a beginner like me.

Comment: From your `main()` call the appropriate function(s).

Comment: You are not **calling** these functions from `main`. You only added their declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of prototypes in `main()`, but no function call.

It should be:

```
int main(void)
{
   enter();
   return 0;
}
```

You seem really confused about how to declare and use functions, perhaps you need some tutorial?

Comment: I know. Just started uni and I have to take programming courses, and I never programmed before. But my brother will help me. Just needed help now...But thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

**simple_interest.h**

```
int enter(void);
double Calc_Interest(double principal, double rate, int term);
double Calc_Amount(double principal, double interest);
double Calc_Payments(double total, int term);
void Display_Results(double principal, double interest, double total, double  mPay);
```

**simple_interest.c**

```
//Implement all functions in this file
#include <stdio.h>

double Calc_Interest(double principal, double rate, int term)
{
        double interest;
        interest = principal * (rate/100) *term;

        return interest;
}

double Calc_Amount(double principal, double interest)
{
        double total;
        total = principal + interest;

        return total;
}

double Calc_Payments(double total, int term)
{
        double mPay;
        mPay= total / (12 * term);

        return mPay;
}
void Display_Results(double principal, double interest, double total, double mPay)
{
        printf("\n");
        printf("Personal Loan Statement\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Amount Borrowed: %.2f\n" , principal);
        printf("Interest on Loan: %.2f\n" , interest);
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Amount of Loan: %.2f\n" , total);
        printf("Monthly Payment: %.2f\n" , mPay);

}
```

**sample.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simple_interest.h"

int enter(void)
{
        double principal, rate, interest, total, mPay;
        int term;

        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("This program calculates the monthly payments due from a personal loan\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

        printf("Enter amount of the loan: ");
        scanf("%lf", &principal);

        printf("Enter current annual interest rate in \n");
        scanf("%lf", &rate);

        printf("Enter the number of years of the loan: ");
        scanf("%d", &term);

        interest = Calc_Interest(principal, rate, term);
        total = Calc_Amount(principal, interest);
        mPay = Calc_Payments(total, term);

        Display_Results(principal, interest, total, mPay);

        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
        enter();
        return 0;
}
```

**compile like this way**

```
gcc sample.c simple_interest.c
./a.out
```